# Accessing AWS Pinpoint from AWS Lambda Node.js 18.x

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-pinpoint

New to AWS Lambda and Node.js. I have a lambda Node.js 18.x trigger.
Using this Lambda, I am sending a Push Notification in APNS channel using Pinpoint

I was using the following statement in my Lambda.
let pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint({region: 'us-east-1'});
This does not seem to work looking at the log.

Would appreciate help with the correct syntax for the call